# How to remove the dirty indicator from the html DOM element in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have big html in that , I need to remove one of the dirty indicator span element , but there are so many dirty indicator in the HTML but I need to remove only the dirty indicator which is present next to "API Key:" label. Please help me. this is my DOM element -

```
<div tabindex="0" class="i-field" data-uid="38aad744-b2b0-4ea2-a47e-fdc06c3d583b">
            <span class="i-label">API Key: </span>
            <span class="i-value">

                <span class="k-dirty "></span>

                2cef8f3c-3969-4720-b4e1-99d91ea16815
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:contains()` to match an element that contains a specific string in the text. And use `.siblings()` to get the other elements that are children of the same parent, which can then be filtered using a selector.

```
$("span.i-label:contains(API Key:)").siblings(".i-value").find(".k-dirty").remove()
```

Comment: Thank you so much , this fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

You can target the elements that are dirty, find out if they are next to an element with the API Key:, and if they are, then remove the class.

```js
$('.k-dirty').closest('[data-uid]').find('.i-label:contains("API Key:")').each(function(){
  $(this).closest('[data-uid]').find('.i-value .k-dirty').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div tabindex="0" class="i-field" data-uid="38aad744-b2b0-4ea2-a47e-fdc06c3d583b">
  <span class="i-label">API Key: </span>
  <span class="i-value">

                <span class="k-dirty "></span> 2cef8f3c-3969-4720-b4e1-99d91ea16815
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much , this fixed my issue

Comment: Isn't this a bit convoluted? You search for .k-dirty, then find the associated .i-value, then find the .k-dirty again.

Comment: @Barmar it's a different approach, targeting the things you want to remove first, rather than targeting the siblings and then trying to find the things you want to remove.  Granted after I saw your answer I prefer it to my own, however I'm leaving this one as a reference.